# Job application form emails are not always receiving (PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, forms, contact-form

I am responsible for a job application form that does not seem to be working well. The problem is that emails from this form are not always receiving. The weird fact is that I also configured a CC email address in this script (another server) and that email address is always receiving mail in that inbox. Personally I think this is a server problem but maybe I am missing something.

UPDATE: Another website is running on that same server with a contact form that appears to be working fine.

See my code below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5SOiIsAziJl6AWe0HWRKTXlfcSHKmYV4RBF18PPJ173Kzn7jzMyFuTtk8JA7QQG1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--[if IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>


</head>



<body>


  <div class="container">


    <div class="content">

      <div style="display:flex; align-items:flex-start; justify-content:flex-start!important; padding:20px 0px 20px 0px; height:100%; flex-wrap:wrap;" class="wrapper">

        <div class="block padding-left">

          <div class="padding-mobile" style="width:100%; height:auto; display:flex; align-items:flex-start; justify-content:flex-start; margin-top:60px; flex-wrap:wrap; box-sizing:border-box;">

            <h2 style="font-size:42px; margin:0px;">Apply</h2>

            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="cv" class="formulier" method="POST" action="">

              <p>
                <label>First name:</label>
                <input data-validation="required" type="text" name="naam" placeholder="Uw naam" />
              </p>

              <p>
                <label>Last name:</label>
                <input data-validation="required" type="text" name="achternaam" placeholder="Uw achternaam" />
              </p>

              <p>
                <label>Telephone</label>
                <input data-validation="required" type="text" name="telefoon" placeholder="Uw telefoonnummer" />
              </p>

              <p>
                <label>Email address</label>
                <input data-validation="required email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Uw email adres" />
              </p>

              <p>
                <label>Select a job application</label>
                <select name="vacature" placeholder="Vacature" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min1" data-validation-error-msg="Selecteer een vacature">
                  <option value="" disable selected>Vacature</option>
                  <option>- Open sollicitatie- </option>
                  <option>Administratief medewerker bedrijfskantoor (m/v)</option>
                  <option>Inkoper</option>
                  <option>Leerling Operators</option>
                  <option>Snijder (m/v)</option>
                  <option>Planner</option>
                  <option>Accountmanager Frankrijk</option>
                  <option>Offsetdrukker Vellen</option>
                  <option>Oproepkrachten</option>
                  <option>Weekend-/ vakantiewerkers</option>
                  <option>Assistent Machineoperator (m/v)</option>
                  <option>Offsetrotatiedrukkers Heatset (m/v)</option>
                  <option>Software developer</option>
                  <option>Allround onderhoudsmonteur</option>
                  <option>Magazijnmedewerker (m/v)</option>
                </select>

              </p>

              <p style="background:#fff; padding:20px; margin-top:44px; color:#000; border-radius:6px;">
                <label style="color:#555; text-shadow:none!important; font-size:18px;">Upload your CV</label>
                <input type="file" name="cv" data-validation="mime size" data-validation-allowing="pdf, docx, doc, docm, rtf" data-validation-max-size="2M" />
              </p>

              <p align="center">Please vrify that you are human.</p>

              <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="---sitekey----" style="margin-bottom:20px;" align="center"></div>

              <input type="submit" value="Verzend mijn sollicitatie!" />

            </form>

            <script>
              $("form#cv")
                .attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data")
                .attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
            </script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
            <script>
              $.validate({
                modules: 'file',
                lang: 'nl'
              });
            </script>



          </div>


        </div>

        <div class="block">

          <div class="circle" style="border-radius:600px; border:solid 10px #fff; margin-top:60px; background:url(wrapper.png); background-size:160% auto!important; background-position:-150px 0!important; box-sizing:border-box;"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>


        <div class="block padding-left inline-block">

          <div style="text-align:center; display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; width:90%;">
            <?php 
     if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
     
     if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
          echo '<div class="notific" style="background:rgba(192, 0, 0, 0.8); display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; border-radius:6px; margin-top:20px; padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;"><i style="margin:0px 10px 0px 10px; color:#fff; font-size:32px; text-shadow: 1.2px 1.2px 1.2px #000;" class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><h2 style="font-size:28px!important;">Bevestig dat u een mens bent.</h2></div>';
  ?>

            <script>
              $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("div.notific").offset().top
              }, 1000)
            </script>

            <?php
          exit;
        }
     
  $secretKey = "--secretkey--";
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
          echo '<div class="notific" style="background:rgba(192, 0, 0, 0.8); display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; border-radius:6px; margin-top:20px; padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;"><i style="margin:0px 10px 0px 10px; color:#fff; font-size:32px; text-shadow: 1.2px 1.2px 1.2px #000;" class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><h2 style="font-size:28px!important;">Er ging iets mis, probeer het nog eens.</h2></div>';
   
  ?>

              <script>
                $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: $("div.notific").offset().top
                }, 1000)
              </script>

              <?php
   
        } else {

          echo '<div class="notific" style="background:rgba(0, 226, 37, 0.8); display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; border-radius:6px; margin-top:20px; padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;"><i style="margin:0px 10px 0px 10px; color:#fff; font-size:32px; text-shadow: 1.2px 1.2px 1.2px #000;" class="fas fa-check-square"></i><h2 style="font-size:28px!important;">Bedankt voor uw aanmelding.</h2></div>';
   
  ?>

                <script>
                  $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("div.notific").offset().top
                  }, 1000)
                </script>

                <?php
        }
      
     }
     
     ?>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>


    <?php
 
 if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_FILES['cv'])) { 
 
  $naam = $_POST['naam'];
  $achternaam = $_POST['achternaam'];
  $telefoon = $_POST['telefoon'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $vacature = $_POST['vacature'];
  
  
  
  $to = 'email@email.com';
  $from = 'email@email.com';

  $subject = 'Nieuwe sollicitatie op vacature';
 
 
  $message = "<p><b>Details sollicitatie:</b></p>
  
  <p>Naam: $naam </p>
  <p>Achternaam: $achternaam </p>
  <p>Telefoon: $telefoon </p>
  <p>Email: $email </p>
  <p>Vacature: $vacature</p> 
  </html>
  ";
  
  
     $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'];
     $file_name        = $_FILES['cv']['name'];
     $file_size        = $_FILES['cv']['size'];
     $file_type        = $_FILES['cv']['type'];
     $file_error       = $_FILES['cv']['error'];
 
     //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
     $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
     $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
     fclose($handle);
     $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
 

    $boundary = md5("em");
        //header
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "From:".$from."\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$to."" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Cc: cc@email.com' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 
 
  
        //plain text 
        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message)); 
        
  
        //attachment
        $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= $encoded_content; 

  mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, '-f email@email.com');
   
 } else {}
  
 if(isset($_POST['email']) && !isset($_FILES['cv'])) { 
 
  $naam = $_POST['naam'];
  $achternaam = $_POST['achternaam'];
  $telefoon = $_POST['telefoon'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $vacature = $_POST['vacature'];
  
  $to = 'email@email.com';
  $from = 'email@email.com';

  $subject = 'Nieuwe sollicitatie op vacature';
 
 
  $message = "<p><b>Details sollicitatie:</b></p>
  
  <p>Naam: $naam </p>
  <p>Achternaam: $achternaam </p>
  <p>Telefoon: $telefoon </p>
  <p>Email: $email </p>
  <p>Vacature: $vacature</p> 
  </html>
  ";
  
  
     $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'];
     $file_name        = $_FILES['cv']['name'];
     $file_size        = $_FILES['cv']['size'];
     $file_type        = $_FILES['cv']['type'];
     $file_error       = $_FILES['cv']['error'];
 
     //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
     $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
     $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
     fclose($handle);
     $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
 

    $boundary = md5("sanwebe");
        //header
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "From:".$from."\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$to."" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Cc: cc@email.com' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 
 
  
        //plain text 
        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message)); 
        
  
        //attachment
        $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= $encoded_content; 

  mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, '-f email@email.com ');
   
 } else {}
 
 ?>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you configured your send mail folder?

Comment: I don't have access to the cpanel of the webserver, but a PHP contact form doesn't need a send mail folder to send emails or do they?

Comment: Try to find proper programmer before this task, then he will nail it. Why not use PHP Mailer library (or other)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

Comment: Use a proper mailer library, as outlined at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/1427878) to the mentioned duplicate. Assembling e-mail _properly_ is a complex issue; the people providing those libraries have the know-how and the solutions are well tested. Don’t waste time trying to implement this yourself using PHP’s `mail`.

Comment: start working on a local server and then execute on hosted server

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience that this type of situation is not related to your code. You could check your phpmail.log but I suspect you will see all of your emails listed.

The key here is that the CC is **always** received. That means your emails are being sent but not delivered. This points to your DNS configuration. It may be your SPF record, or lack of a DKIM entry.

Since you are using PHP's mail() function, you are not sending via authenticated SMTP. I would second @CBroe's recommendation to use a mail library, but for a different reason. It will provide you the option of using authenticated SMTP which will have a much higher possibility of delivery.

I would recommend:

- Check your SPF Record and make sure it includes your server's IP address. Preferably it will end with "-all" (avoid "+all").
- Use a PHP mail library and use authenticated SMTP. This isn't a requirement, but it makes coding email faster, easier and less error prone. Authenticated SMTP never hurts your chances of delivery.
- If possible, set up the DKIM record for your domain.